# Heroku cron job help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How do I run the task reklamer:runall every 15 minutes in cron.rake?

```
I have my cron.rake file:
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
  if Time.now.hour % 4 == 0 # run every four hours
    puts "Updating feed..."
    NewsFeed.update
    puts "done."
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku only provides daily or hourly cron jobs so I think you're out of luck with running cron jobs every 15 minutes.

Instead, you could use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to run jobs every 15 minutes. At the end of each run, your job code should create another job which will run in 15 minutes. You could calculate 15 minutes from the start or the end of the job, depending on your needs.

Comment: Yes, you will need a worker. You could try to use something like HireFire (https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) to minimise the cost.

Comment: There are examples at https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job. The key thing is to use :run_at parameter when creating your jobs to specify when they should run.

Comment: just for info, are these delayed_jobs run separately from the application? can I run a job which looks into my application for any crashes etc. ? or an application crash will fail all the jobs too ?

Comment: delayed_job workers are separate processes from your app. The only way they exchange information with the application is via the database, so you'd have to record information about exceptions in the database and then have a delayed job handle it.