# Rails how to create an background task for a rake task on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails delayed job not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674880/rails-delayed-job-not-working)

How do I create an background task that should run every 15 minutes on heroku?

How to do the periodic scraping with clockwork and delayed_job are some other plugsins/gems?

My rake file:

```
desc "Importer statistikker"
namespace :reklamer do
task :runall => [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville ] do
  # This will run after all those tasks have run
end

      task :iqmedier => :environment do
              require 'Mechanize'
              agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
              agent.get("http://www.iqmedier.dk")
              agent.page.link_with(:href => "/Publisher/Stats").click
              form = agent.page.forms.first
              form.submit

              @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')[-2]

              @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
              if @existing.nil?
                  Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
              elsif @existing.dato != Date.today
              Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => Date.today, :unik_klik => 0, :klik => 0, :unik_vis => 0, :vis => 0, :leads => 0, :ordre => 0, :cpc => 0, :earn => 0)
              else
                @existing.update_attributes!(:leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
              end
      end
      task :euroads => :environment do
            require 'Mechanize'
            require 'pp'
            agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
            agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'}
            agent.get("http://www.euroads.dk")
            @stats =  agent.page.search('table.ea')

            @existing = Reklamer.find(:first)
            if @existing.nil?
                Reklamer.create!(:klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
            elsif @existing.dato != Date.today
              Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Euroads', :dato => Date.today, :unik_klik => 0, :klik => 0, :unik_vis => 0, :vis => 0, :leads => 0, :ordre => 0, :cpc => 0, :earn => 0)
            else
              @existing.update_attributes(:unik_klik => :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
            end
      end

      task :mikkelsen => :environment do
            require 'Mechanize'
            agent = Mechanize.new
            agent.get("http://affilate.mikkelsenmedia.dk")
            @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')[-5].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }

            @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0] })
            if @existing.nil?
                Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Mikkelsen', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[3], :klik => @stats[3].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[4], :ordre => @stats[9], :cpc => @stats[3], :earn => @stats[5])
            else
                @existing.update_attributes(:virksomhed => 'Mikkelsen', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[3], :klik => @stats[3].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[4], :ordre => @stats[9], :cpc => @stats[3], :earn => @stats[5])
            end
       end
      task :orville => :environment do
            require 'Mechanize'
            agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
            agent.get("https://dk.orvillemedia.com")
            @dato = Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s
            @month = Date.today.strftime("%m").to_s
            @day = Date.today.strftime("%d").to_s
            agent.get("https://dk.orvillemedia.com/publisher/stats.php?sd=#{@day}&sm=#{@month}")
            @stats = agent.page.search('td')

            @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @dato})
            if @existing.nil?
                Reklamer.create!(:vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[3], :ordre => '0')
            else
              @existing.update_attributes(:ordre => '0', :cpc => (@stats[5] == '-' ? 0 : @stats[3]), :earn => @stats[6])
            end
       end
       end
```

Comment: You can find the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643192/heroku-cron-job-help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643192/heroku-cron-job-help)

Comment: How do I make an delayed_job for my rake task?

Comment: Please can anybody help me I have been stuck with this for 2.5 weeks now and I havent found any solution

Comment: There is a big different between delayed jobs and cron jobs. A cron job is usually something what is running every x min/hour/day or every day at a given time. If you need something like that, you don't need the gem delayed job. For that use case I wrote a complete blog post how to do it with heroku workers dyno and rake. See here: http://robert-reiz.com/2012/06/12/cron-jobs-on-heroku/.

Delayed Job is for a different use case. If your Rails App take requests and have to process background work asynchrony, than usually you take the delayed_job gem to do the background work later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
```

In lib/scraper.rb:

```
class Scraper
  def perform
    # All the scraping code you need to run goes here.
  end

  def error(job, exception)
    # Send a warning email to yourself, or whatever.
    # The scraping will automatically be retried.
  end

  def success(job)
    # Schedule the next scraping.
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new, :run_at => 15.minutes.from_now)
  end
end
```

Then start up the initial Scraper, and it'll handle things from there. In the heroku console, run:

```
Scraper.new.perform
```

You'll need to have a worker running all the time in order to run the scrapings.

Comment: Cant I use hire and fire to minimise the cost?

Comment: According to hirefire's github readme, it's not compatible with run_at, so no.

Comment: I think it might me compatible with hirefire, but you must set min workers to 1. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you hourly tasks:
http://addons.heroku.com/cron

Comment: Yes hourly I need every 15 minute

Comment: The Cron Add-On on Heroku is deprecated. Instead of the Cron Add-On you should use now the Scheduler Add-On: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler